# Second activity will not populate

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, csv

I've spent the last 2 weeks on this site trying to piece together code to make this app do what I want. I know I'm close. I know I'm damn close. But it just will not populate anything in the second activity.

As far as I can tell, this Activity is working fine. The only thing I don't know is if the file is actually being written to correctly, but when I Toast the output that should be going to the file, it returns the correct data.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
double MOA;
TextView turretClicks;
boolean noMOA;
double clicks;

String stringRange;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    turretClicks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.turretClicks);



    // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
    View.OnClickListener btnClickCalc = new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicks = (MOA * 4);
            String stringClicks = String.valueOf(clicks);

//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, clicks + " Clicks",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            EditText range = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rangeEntry);
            stringRange = range.getText().toString();
            turretClicks.setText(stringClicks);

            int finalRange = Integer.parseInt(stringRange);
            if (finalRange <= 200) {
                MOA = 0;
            }
            if (finalRange > 200 && finalRange <= 225) {
                MOA = .5;
            }
            if (finalRange > 225 && finalRange <= 250) {
                MOA = 1;
            }
            if (finalRange > 250 && finalRange <= 275) {
                MOA = 1.65;
            }
            if (finalRange > 275 && finalRange <= 300) {
                MOA = 2.25;
            }
            if (finalRange > 300 && finalRange <= 325) {
                MOA = 2.8;
            }
            if (finalRange > 325 && finalRange <= 350) {
                MOA = 3.5;
            }
            if (finalRange > 350 && finalRange <= 375) {
                MOA = 4.0;
            }
            if (finalRange > 375 && finalRange <= 400) {
                MOA = 4.75;
            }
            if (finalRange > 400 && finalRange <= 425) {
                MOA = 5.50;
            }
            if (finalRange > 425 && finalRange <= 450) {
                MOA = 6.25;
            }
            if (finalRange > 450 && finalRange <= 475) {
                MOA = 7.0;
            }
            if (finalRange > 475 && finalRange <= 500) {
                MOA = 7.5;
            }
            if (finalRange > 500 && finalRange <= 525) {
                MOA = 8.25;
            }
            if (finalRange > 525 && finalRange <= 550) {
                MOA = 9.0;
            }
            if (finalRange > 550 && finalRange <= 575) {
                MOA = 9.75;
            }
            if (finalRange > 575 && finalRange <= 600) {
                MOA = 10.5;
            }
            if (finalRange > 600 && finalRange <= 625) {
                MOA = 11.5;
            }
            if (finalRange > 625 && finalRange <= 650) {
                MOA = 12.25;
            }
            if (finalRange > 650 && finalRange <= 675) {
                MOA = 13;
            }
            if (finalRange > 675 && finalRange <= 700) {
                MOA = 14;
            }
            if (finalRange > 700) {
                noMOA = true;
            }


        }
    };


    // Capture our button from layout
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClickCalc);
    // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
    button.setOnClickListener(btnClickCalc);



    final View.OnClickListener btnRecordRange = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, clicks + " Clicks " + "@ " + stringRange + " yards", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            try {
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("recordings.csv", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
                outputStreamWriter.write("Clicks" + " " + clicks + "," + 
" " + "@Range" + stringRange + "\n");
                outputStreamWriter.close();
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, recordableClicks 
+ " " + recordableRange, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
            }

        }

    };

    // Capture our button from layout
    Button recordRange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordRange);
    // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
    recordRange.setOnClickListener(btnRecordRange);
    // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener



    final View.OnClickListener btnToRecorded = new 
View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new 
Intent(MainActivity.this,RangeRecords.class));

        }

    };

    // Capture our button from layout
    Button showRecords = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnToRecorded);
    // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
    showRecords.setOnClickListener(btnToRecorded);
    // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener

}

}
```

**RangeRecords.java**

```
public class RangeRecords extends Activity {
public static TextView ListItems;
private RelativeLayout lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_recorded_ranges);
    readFromFile("recordings.csv");
    lv = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLay);
}


public String readFromFile(String fname) {
    String ret = "";
    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<>();


    try {
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fname);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(fis));

        for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line =  
br.readLine()) {
            ar.add(line);

                for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++){
                    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                    textView.setText(ar.get(i));
                    lv.addView(textView);
                }
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: Target File Cannot Be Read");
    }


    return ret;
}
}
```

**Assume that all imports are correct.**

**content_main.xml**
Everything here works correctly. All the data is displayed and the buttons work correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#000000">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate MOA"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate Clicks"
    android:id="@+id/btnClickCalc"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:onClick="calcClick"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rangeEntry"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/turretClicks"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:hint="0"
    android:background="#c2c0c0"
    android:layout_marginTop="106dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnClickCalc"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/rangeEntry"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:hint="Enter Range"
    android:background="#c2c0c0"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Clicks"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/turretClicks"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#c2c0c0"
    android:textColor="#fc0000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="To Recorded Ranges"
    android:id="@+id/btnToRecorded"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Record Clicks for Range"
    android:id="@+id/btnRecordRange"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_recorded_range.xml**

**When I switch to this activity/view, the screen is black except for the status bar (signal, time, etc) which is sort of blurred over white. Nothing populates here at all.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/relativeLay"
android:background="#000000" >
```

What am I missing here?

MainActivity calculates the clicks for the scope turrets @ X range. The next button records this data to a csv file. The next button switches you to the next activity which should onCreate display the data from the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. It appears to me that the UI is difficult to understand when getting in to Java. I can't recall exactly how I fixed this, but for those who may come to this thread facing similar issues, dig deep in to how your UI works, and check out this video to better understand how layouts work in UI in Android:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6c3DGnvefY

After watching this video, IIRC, I figured out that one of my layouts was overlapping another and that the textviews were never being created. I ultimately broke the entire code apart. I stopped using File reader and writer and began using Shared Preferences, which work phenomenally better at simple tasks like I'm trying to accomplish. Again, consider your UI, watch the video to better understand how to get started with UI, and look at how complicated your UI is. More than likely, you are trying to do too much too fast, which was my case. :)